# SQL: Take the max of two columns based off of first column

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have three columns being returned Column one is a system generated "ID" column two is the warehouse and the third column is the total that warehouse shows on that ID. There are duplicate ID's Im trying to figure out how to take the max count of the Warehouse and get the greatest warehouse on that ID for example:

```
id  WH  Count   
TRL0520841  6   2   Takes the greatest WH based on the greatest QTY 
TRL0520841  2   2   
TRL0520841  5   1   
TRL0525482  6   15  Takes the greatest WH based on the greatest QTY
TRL0525482  2   9
```

in other words TRL0520841 would have a result of 6 and TRL0525482 would have a result of 6

```
    select *
from (select ar2.trlr_id,
            to_number(ar2.area) areanum,
            ar2.con
       from (select ar1.trlr_id,
                    ar1.area,
                    count(ar1.area) con
               from (SELECT t.trlr_id,
                            pm.prtnum,
                            case when pm.prtfam like 'WH%' then substr(pm.prtfam, 3, 1)
                                 else '6'
                            end area
                       FROM rcvtrk rt,
                            trlr t,
                            rcvlin rl,
                            prtftp pf,
                            prtftp_dtl pfd,
                            prtmst pm
                      where t.trlr_id = rt.trlr_id
                        and t.trlr_stat not in ('D', 'C')
                        and rl.trknum = rt.trknum
                        and rl.prtnum = pf.prtnum
                        and pfd.prtnum = pf.prtnum
                        and pfd.ftpcod = pf.ftpcod
                        and pf.defftp_flg = '1'
                        and pfd.uomcod = 'UL'
                        and pfd.wh_id = 'CP01'
                        AND pf.wh_id = 'CP01'
                        and pf.prtnum = pm.prtnum
                        and t.yard_loc is not null
                        and t.trlr_cod = 'RCV'
                        and t.yard_loc_wh_id = 'CP01'
                      group by t.trlr_id,
                            pm.prtnum,
                            pm.prtfam) ar1
              group by ar1.trlr_id,
                    ar1.area) ar2) ar3;
```

Comment: Why are you storing the area as a varchar?

Comment: Because it is a number. At one point I thought about using a case statement to pull a count of the Trlr_id based off of the area

Comment: If it **is** a `number`, then `to_number(ar2.area)` makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry about that I had it reversed. It started out as a text such as WH6, WH1, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you can use ROW_NUMBER() to determine which of the rows you wish to retain in the final result. Note you may want to include other columns in the ORDER BY of that calculation as tie breakers.

```
SELECT
      ar3.trlr_id
    , ar3.areanum
    , ar3.con
FROM (
      SELECT
            ar2.trlr_id
          , ar2.areanum
          , ar2.con
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ar2.trlr_id ORDER BY ar2.areanum, ar2.con DESC) as rn
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  ar1.trlr_id
                , ar1.areanum
                , COUNT(ar1.areanum) con
            FROM (
                  SELECT
                        t.trlr_id
                      , pm.prtnum
                      , to_number(CASE
                              WHEN pm.prtfam LIKE 'WH%' THEN substr(pm.prtfam, 3, 1)
                              ELSE '6'
                        END) areanum
                  FROM rcvtrk rt
                     , trlr t
                     , rcvlin rl
                     , prtftp pf
                     , prtftp_dtl pfd
                     , prtmst pm
                  WHERE t.trlr_id = rt.trlr_id
                        AND t.trlr_stat NOT IN ('D', 'C')
                        AND rl.trknum = rt.trknum
                        AND rl.prtnum = pf.prtnum
                        AND pfd.prtnum = pf.prtnum
                        AND pfd.ftpcod = pf.ftpcod
                        AND pf.defftp_flg = '1'
                        AND pfd.uomcod = 'UL'
                        AND pfd.wh_id = 'CP01'
                        AND pf.wh_id = 'CP01'
                        AND pf.prtnum = pm.prtnum
                        AND t.yard_loc IS NOT NULL
                        AND t.trlr_cod = 'RCV'
                        AND t.yard_loc_wh_id = 'CP01'
                  GROUP BY
                        t.trlr_id
                      , pm.prtnum
                      , pm.prtfam
                  ) ar1
            GROUP BY
                  ar1.trlr_id
                , ar1.areanum
            ) ar2
      ) ar3
WHERE ar3.rn = 1
;
```

By the way: It was a very long time ago that ANSI join syntax was adopted. It really is time to stop using the where clause for all joins. Like this (untested):

```
SELECT
      *
FROM rcvtrk rt
      INNER JOIN trlr t ON rt.trlr_id = t.trlr_id
      INNER JOIN rcvlin rl ON rt.trknum = rl.trknum
      INNER JOIN prtftp pf ON rl.prtnum = pf.prtnum
      INNER JOIN prtftp_dtl pfd ON pf.prtnum = pfd.prtnum
                  AND pf.ftpcod = pfd.ftpcod
      INNER JOIN prtmst pm ON pf.prtnum = pm.prtnum
WHERE t.trlr_stat NOT IN ('D', 'C')
      AND t.yard_loc IS NOT NULL
      AND t.trlr_cod = 'RCV'
      AND t.yard_loc_wh_id = 'CP01'
      AND pf.defftp_flg = '1'
      AND pf.wh_id = 'CP01'
      AND pfd.uomcod = 'UL'
      AND pfd.wh_id = 'CP01'
```

Comment: Thank you. This has helped my greatly

Comment: No problem, I added the ANSI join syntax FYI

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column names are 'id', 'WH' and 'Count', and that the table name is 'dbo.Warehouse', the query you need is:

```
SELECT Warehouse.id, WH, Count
FROM dbo.Warehouse as Warehouse
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id, MAX(Count) AS MaxCount
    FROM dbo.Warehouse
    GROUP BY id) as groupedWH 
ON Warehouse.id = groupedWH.id
AND Count = groupedWH.MaxCount
```

For IDs with duplicate maximums, this will return all such rows (e.g. for TRL0520841 in your example both rows with count = 2 will be returned); you'll need to decide how to handle that.

Comment: Why did you add a schema (`dbo`)  name that isn't present in the original query? Also: Oracle doesn't support `AS` for table aliases